# Where are sourcempas located and how do I generate them in Sveltekit?

Tags: source-maps, sveltekit

I cannot find them anywhere, I don't even see that they are being created when I run npm run build. I am using the latest version of sveltekit with typescript. I would assume the sourcemaps would be located in the output folder of the .svelte-kit directory but no dice.

```
// svelte.config.js
...
const config = {
   compilerOptions: {
      enableSourcemap: true
   },
   preprocess: [
      preprocess({
         postcss: true,
         sourceMap: true
      })
   ],
   kit: {
      adapter: vercel(),
      methodOverride: {
         allowed: ['PATCH', 'DELETE']
      },
   }
};

export default config;
```

I also have `sourceMap: true` under the compilerOptions of my tsconfig.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SvelteKit 1.0.0-next.350 with adapter-node and `npm run build` puts result files to `<project root>/build` directory, not to `<project root>/.svelte-kit`. It is because the build out dir for adapter-node is set [in the adapter](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-node#options).

Try to check the adapter you are actually using. Maybe the out dir for adapter-vercel is [`<project root>/.vercel_build_output`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/%40sveltejs/kit%401.0.0-next.350/packages/adapter-vercel/index.js#L112) or [`<project root>/.vercel/output`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/%40sveltejs/kit%401.0.0-next.350/packages/adapter-vercel/index.js#L209)?

Also you can try to enable this sourcemap option:

```
export default {
    kit: {
        vite: {
            build: {
                sourcemap: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the missing link, thank you!

Comment: Vite config options is moved to `vite.config.js`.

Comment: specifically, `export default defineConfig({ ..., `[`build: { sourcemap`](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-sourcemap)`: "inline"`